# Page not found (404) add comment

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

hi i guys i am trying to add comment on my django project but i get 404 error and i dont know why is that
here is my code :

urls.py

```
    re_path(r'(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/' , views.details , name="details"),
    path('comment/<prId>)' , views.comment , name='comment'),
```

views.py

```
def details(request , slug):
    pr = get_object_or_404(Product , slug=slug)
    category = Category.objects.all()
    id1 = pr.category.id
    similar = Product.objects.filter(category_id=id1)
    pr.view = F('view')+1
    pr.save()
    context = {
        'products': pr,
        'similar' : similar,
        'category' : category
    }
    return render(request, "prDetails.html" , context)

def comment(request, prId):
    pr = get_object_or_404(Product ,id=prId)
    pr2 = pr.slug

    cm = Comment(
        name=request.POST.get('name', ''),
        email=request.POST.get('email' , ''),
        text=request.POST.get('text', ''),
        products=pr
    )
    cm.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('details', args=(pr2,)))
```

and here is my error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/comment/1/
Raised by:  main.views.details
No Product matches the given query.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def comment(request, prId):
    pr = get_object_or_404(Product ,id=prId)
```

did you create any comment in the database?

Comment: yes i did i found the problem its because of re_path